# how to move jenkins_home with all jobs and settings in windows

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

i have a jenkins installation running in a tomcat server, and i kept the default settings so my jenkins home is in C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile.jenkins.

after creating my jobs, i now want to relocate my jenkins_home and added

```
<Environment name="JENKINS_HOME" value="D:/jenkins_home/" type="java.lang.String"/>
```

to my context.xml of the tomcat.

This works but its a "virgin" installation of jenkins, and i would like to keep the jobs, settings and users.
What could i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the old jenkins folder to the new location and restart Jenkins.

I just did that on a linux (via yum) installation.

Should be working the same on Windows.

Comment: i tried this, but i cant log into jenkins anymore. After restarting the application server i got the message "To ensure Jenkins is securely set up by the administrator, a password has been written to the log ..." and initialAdminPassword isn't accepted and my "old" admin pw doesn't work either.